# example usage of ~kiri

Tags: grammar

It seems that one of the uses of ~kiri is to show continuance of state/condition.
is it similar to '~ta mama' then?

However,i have not been able to find an example of this usage.
Appreciate help.

Comment: Unless you are googling in romaji, you should be able to find plenty of examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will just form a few phrases with the particle 「きり」.

「[寝]{ね}た**きり**[老人]{ろうじん}」 = "(a) bedridden elderly person(s)"

「マリアは2[年前]{ねんまえ}[日本]{にほん}に[行]{い}った**きり**[帰]{かえ}ってこない。」 = "Maria went to Japan 2 years ago and has not returned since."

「[窓]{まど}は[閉]{し}め**っきり**にしないで、たまには[開]{あ}けて[空気]{くうき}を[入]{い}れ[替]{か}えてね。」 = "Don't keep your windows shut all the time.  Crack'em open once in a while for ventilation."

Note: In informal speech, 「きり」 is often pronounced 「っきり」, but remember not to use 「っきり」 in a phrase like 「寝たきり老人」 because you will end up sounding like you have grudges against those elderly.