# 納骨堂は８年前に使われたきりだって - What does きり mean in that sentence?

Tags: grammar

Context:

https://streamable.com/dw69vn

A: とにかく 扉を開けたとたんに死体が倒れてきたということは鍵を掛けられた時点では生きていたということだ。閉じ込められ助けを求めたまま力尽きた。

B: 納骨堂は８年前に使われた**きり**だって

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18898/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5855/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59207/9831